# How to calculate a contingency table?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, datatool

I am trying to calculate a contingency table of two discrete variables `name` and `location`. Missing levels should be 0, while each cell should be the count of each name-location combination. My initial approach was to create counters and then format them into a table, but I am not sure how to nest the if-statements. Also, I assume there must be a datatool approach?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{fruit.csv}
name,location
Apple,NY
Apple,LA
Orange,LA
Banana,LA
Banana,NY
Banana,NY
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{fruit}{fruit.csv}
\newcounter{applyNY}

\begin{document}


\DTLforeach*{fruit}{\name=name,\loc=location}{%
    \IfStrEqCase{\name}{%
     {Apple}{\IfStrEqCase{\loc}{NY}
        {\stepcounter{applyNY}}}%
    }%
}


There are \theapplyNY 

\end{document}
```

The output following my approach is

> There are 2

while I was looking to get 1 (those that are name = Apple & location = NY)

Comment: I wouldn't use `\l` as your loop variable as that command is already defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a pair of braces:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{fruit.csv}
name,location
Apple,NY
Apple,LA
Orange,LA
Banana,LA
Banana,NY
Banana,NY
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{fruit}{fruit.csv}
\newcounter{applyNY}

\begin{document}


\DTLforeach*{fruit}{\name=name,\loc=location}{%
  \IfStrEqCase{\name}{%
    {Apple}{%
      \IfStrEqCase{\loc}{%<--- This was missing
        {NY}{\stepcounter{applyNY}}%
      }%<--- This was missing
    }%
}}

There are \theapplyNY 

\end{document}
```

Check and you'll find the number printed is 1.

A fairly more general version, where you can extract the values once loaded the database and also print the contingency table itself.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{fruit.csv}
name,location
Apple,NY
Apple,LA
Orange,LA
Banana,LA
Banana,NY
Banana,NY
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\loadcontingencytable}{mmm}
 {% #1 = DB name
  % #2 = first col name
  % #3 = second col name
  \dambo_ct_load:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\getcontingencytablevalue}{mmm}
 {
  \dambo_ct_getvalue:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\showcontingencytable}{m}
 {
  \dambo_ct_show:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__dambo_ct_row_tl
\tl_new:N \l__dambo_ct_col_tl
\tl_new:N \l__dambo_ct_rowcol_tl
\tl_new:N \l__dambo_ct_body_tl
\int_new:N \l__dambo_ct_cols_int
\seq_new:N \l__dambo_ct_rows_tl
\seq_new:N \l__dambo_ct_cols_tl
\prop_new:N \l__dambo_ct_table_prop

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { NVx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { NV, cx }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \dambo_ct_load:nnn
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_dambo_ct_rows_#1_seq }
  \seq_new:c { g_dambo_ct_cols_#1_seq }
  \prop_new:c { g_dambo_ct_table_#1_prop }
  \seq_clear:N \l__dambo_ct_rows_seq
  \seq_clear:N \l__dambo_ct_cols_seq
  \prop_clear:N \l__dambo_ct_table_prop

  \DTLforeach*{#1}
   {
    \l__dambo_ct_row_tl = #2,\l__dambo_ct_col_tl = #3
   }
   {
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__dambo_ct_rows_seq \l__dambo_ct_row_tl
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__dambo_ct_cols_seq \l__dambo_ct_col_tl
    \tl_set:Nx \l__dambo_ct_rowcol_tl
     {
      \exp_not:V \l__dambo_ct_row_tl
      \exp_not:V \l__dambo_ct_col_tl
     }
    \prop_put:NVx \l__dambo_ct_table_prop \l__dambo_ct_rowcol_tl
     {
      \int_eval:n
       {
        0\prop_item:NV \l__dambo_ct_table_prop \l__dambo_ct_rowcol_tl + 1
       }
     }
   }
  \seq_remove_duplicates:N \l__dambo_ct_rows_seq
  \seq_remove_duplicates:N \l__dambo_ct_cols_seq
  \seq_set_eq:cN { g_dambo_ct_rows_#1_seq } \l__dambo_ct_rows_seq
  \seq_set_eq:cN { g_dambo_ct_cols_#1_seq } \l__dambo_ct_cols_seq
  \prop_set_eq:cN { g_dambo_ct_table_#1_prop } \l__dambo_ct_table_prop
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \dambo_ct_getvalue:nnn
 {
  \prop_item:cn { g_dambo_ct_table_#1_prop } { #2#3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \dambo_ct_show:n
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l__dambo_ct_cols_int { \seq_count:c { g_dambo_ct_cols_#1_seq } }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__dambo_ct_body_tl
   {
    & \seq_use:cn { g_dambo_ct_cols_#1_seq } { & }
    \exp_not:n { \\ \midrule }
   }
  \seq_map_inline:cn { g_dambo_ct_rows_#1_seq }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__dambo_ct_body_tl { ##1 }
    \int_step_inline:nn { \l__dambo_ct_cols_int }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__dambo_ct_body_tl
       {
        &
        \prop_item:cx { g_dambo_ct_table_#1_prop }
         { ##1 \seq_item:cn { g_dambo_ct_cols_#1_seq } { ####1 } }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__dambo_ct_body_tl { \\ }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{ l *{\l__dambo_ct_cols_int}{c} }
  \toprule
  \tl_use:N \l__dambo_ct_body_tl
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DTLloaddb{fruit}{fruit.csv}
\loadcontingencytable{fruit}{name}{location}

\begin{document}

Apple, NY: \getcontingencytablevalue{fruit}{Apple}{NY}

Banana, NY: \getcontingencytablevalue{fruit}{Banana}{NY}

\bigskip

\showcontingencytable{fruit}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if I should open a new question, but I was wondering whether doing multiple counts is how I want to calculate contingency tables, or whether there is a more efficient way of doing it using datatools.

Comment: @Dambo I added a more general version, where the computations are done just once.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I guess the message is: create the contingency table outside latex, then load it :)

Comment: @Dambo Why? You can do it in LaTeX, as shown. Maybe external tools could be faster.

Comment: Because say that I load a new dataset with more/less levels on one variable...then I should change the latex code too. As an absolute beginner, I was hoping in a more robust solution

Comment: @Dambo This works for *any* two-column dataset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82880/discussion-between-dambo-and-egreg).